# With MYSQL, how to group a list of direct relationships into mutually exclusive networks?

Tags: mysql

Relationship Table

| Source | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| E | F |
| G | H |
| E | H |

The Output I want:

| Group_id | Person |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | E |
| 2 | F |
| 2 | G |
| 2 | H |

Explanation for the output: 
A connects with B, B connects with C, so A, B, C are in the same network.

The same logic applies for E,F,G,H

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: We'd need to know the constraints on the data-model.  It's clear that one person can associate to multiple sources, and vice versa, so do you allow cycles?  `a -> b -> c -> a -> repeats forever`, for example.  What about duplicate associations?  `a -> b` in two different rows of the table, or `a -> b` and `a -> c -> b`, etc, etc.  Please be very specific about everything that can and can not happen in you relsationships.

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, cycle can exist.

Comment: ***Please be very specific about EVERYTHING that CAN and CAN NOT happen in your relationships.***

Answer (score -1):

Please check this: I hope It is the kind of solution you are looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T01.Source AS Person, 1 AS Group_id FROM (SELECT T1.Source, T1.Target FROM (SELECT ascii(Source) as id01, Source, Target, ascii(Target) as id02 
FROM RelationshipTable
WHERE ascii(Source) <= (SELECT MIN(ascii(Target)) FROM RelationshipTable)
) AS T1) AS T01
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT T02.Target, 1 AS Group_id FROM (SELECT T2.Source, T2.Target FROM (SELECT ascii(Source) as id01, Source, Target, ascii(Target) as id02 
FROM RelationshipTable
WHERE ascii(Source) <= (SELECT MIN(ascii(Target)) FROM RelationshipTable)
) AS T2) AS T02
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT H01.Source, 2 AS Group_id FROM (SELECT R.Source,R.Target FROM (SELECT ascii(Source) as id01, Source, Target, ascii(Target) as id02 
FROM RelationshipTable
WHERE ascii(Source) <= (SELECT MIN(ascii(Target)) FROM RelationshipTable)
) AS T RIGHT JOIN RelationshipTable AS R ON T.Source = R.Source WHERE T.source is null) AS H01
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT H02.Target, 2 AS Group_id FROM (SELECT R.Source,R.Target FROM (SELECT ascii(Source) as id01, Source, Target, ascii(Target) as id02 
FROM RelationshipTable
WHERE ascii(Source) <= (SELECT MIN(ascii(Target)) FROM RelationshipTable)
) AS T RIGHT JOIN RelationshipTable AS R ON T.Source = R.Source WHERE T.source is null) AS H02
ORDER BY Person;
```

If we test it, It returns:

[image: KKC]

Comment: And what if there are three distinct groups?

Comment: Then 2 more union with a little change in code is required. More groups mean longer and more tedious code.

Comment: My point is that you don't necessarily know how many groups there will be in the dataset.

Comment: Is there any extra info about how many groups there will be ? No! All we can see is 2 different groups; so our judgement is based on this. What if 999999 ... distinct group existed, what would you do then ? What I am saying is that different needs require different strategy. For the existing one involving 2 groups my answer is correct even if somebody voted it down. (It is probably you).

Comment: If the OP answered my questions, I'd write a recursive tree traversal that is resilient to any valid data set. I would not provide an answer that only works for an extremely limited data set, and has very little generalisation. Much as I have been doing for Years on SO. (Yes, I voted your answer down, as I consider it a bad answer. Apparently no-one considers it a good answer.)

Comment: If you vote down  a solution seconds after it is posted , then I say you have an evil intent and manipulating people to believe something . Keep voting down. I would never do these kind of things . All you need is respect !!

Comment: If I add a relationship for `Source C, Target D` then your code fails.  An answer that only works for ***example*** data is a bad answer.  Your answer may as well be hardcoded as `SELECT 'A' AS Person, 1 AS Group_id UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'E', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'F', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'G', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'H', 2`   Also, your use of `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` exposes significant overheads.  This is a bad answer, sorry you are offended by being told that.  You escalated this to emotive language and allegations, not me.

Comment: I am not offended. I hope you solve it in the best way. Good luck. I think our discussion is finished.